# trying to insert different result sets by using single insert statement by checking condition

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, insert, mysql-error-1064

i have a winform  with four textboxes and  two dropdown lists and a Save button

textboxes are like these

- Startdate textbox with value entered in the textbox   2011-03-02
  (yyyy-mm-dd)
- Enddate textbox with value entered in textbox 2013-09-04 (yyyy-mm-dd)
- due day text box, value entered in that textbox is (2011-03-15)  (15
  th of march 2011)
- amonut due textbox with value entered in that textbox is 120.00.
- paymentoption  dropdownlist with values   12 months cash, 24 months
  cash
- paid option dropdownlist with values yearly , monthly

and i have a table

```
       paymentschedule 
     columns:         paymentscheduleid
                      datetobepaid
                      amountdue
                      paymentoption
```

when you click on save button the values are saved in table like below set

this will be the resultset if "paid option" is monthly  and the result set is given below (paid option is monthly)

```
  paymentscheduleid      datetobepaid      amountdue      paymentoption

       1                   2011-04-15        120.00        12 months cash
       2                   2011-05-15        120.00        12 months cash
       3                   2011-06-15        120.00        12 months cash
       4                   2011-07-15        120.00        12 months cash
       -                       -              -                  -
       -                       -              -                  -
       -                       -              -                  -
       20                 2013-08-15        120.00         12 months cash
```

if paid option is yearly then the result set will be like this (paid option is yearly)

```
       paymentscheduleid      datetobepaid      amountdue      paymentoption

             1                  2011-04-15        120.00         12 month cash
             2                  2012-04-15        120.00         12 months cash
             3                  2013-04-15        120.00         12 months cash
```

the datetobpaid depends on startdate and the value entered in the due day textbox

is it possible to use single insertstatement using mysql and c#

would any one help on this problem

many thanks......

Comment: what you want to do reload data after insertion or something else

Comment: @shoaib after inserting the data i have to retrieve the entire list data and i have  to show the data using list view.....

Comment: you want to reloaded data depends on paid option?

Comment: paid option need to be check before the insert statement and i want to show the inserted data in  list view in different form..

Comment: i think you need to check paid option and then run query according to it!

Comment: is there if condition check in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly run on MS Sql you can change it to Mysql as you need:

```
declare @DueDate Datetime
declare @EndDate Datetime

declare @PaidOption varchar(10)
set @PaidOption='Monthly'

set @DueDate='2011-03-15'
set @EndDate='2013-09-04'


if @PaidOption='Monthly' -- for monthly
Begin
set @DueDate=DATEADD(month,+1,@DueDate)
WHILE @DueDate<@EndDate
BEGIN  
--insert statement use @duedate for datetobepaid and other values are as you input
  set @DueDate=DATEADD(month,+1,@DueDate)

END
End
Else -- for yearly
Begin
set @DueDate=DATEADD(Year,+1,@DueDate)
WHILE @DueDate<@EndDate
BEGIN  
--insert statement use @duedate for datetobepaid and other values are as you input
  set @DueDate=DATEADD(year,+1,@DueDate)

END
End
```

here Paidoption and other fields are set statically .Although you can use it as input parameters

Hope This May Solve your problem

Comment: @ shoaib  thanq but  here is no option to write store procedures in mysql this should be done in single insertion  statement using mysql

Comment: you can save this whole query in string variable and set sqlcommand to "Exec(String Variable Name)"

Comment: those are text boxe values, is there any way comparison will be done in c# by using this comparison we can insert  values into my sql statement by using string cocatenation like     option+="' period'"......

Comment: and another thing is i cannot use sql command here the procedure is like this data will be passing through webservice thats why i asked this checking should be done in single sql insertion statement